# how can I make wcf service concurrency work?

Tags: c#, http, wcf, web, concurrency

I am new in wcf,I concurrent 10 request to test my wcf service but just response in random，3,7,1,sometimes even no response. I have search a lot and fill some code in web.config,set the currencymod,instancemode,but result still haven't any changes.I
hope someone could help check my code.

the concerned code in wcf service web.config

```
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
<httpRuntime />
<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" /></system.web>
<endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="ADGrainWcfService.ISQLiteHelperService" />
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />

  <behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>

      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />

      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
      <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="200" maxConcurrentSessions="5000" maxConcurrentInstances="200" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<protocolMapping>
  <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
</protocolMapping>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>      
<bindingname="basicHttpBinding"closeTimeout="00:30:00"openTimeout="00:30:00" receiveTimeout="00:30:00" sendTimeout="00:30:00"transferMode="Buffered"hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
 maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
  </binding>

 </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<system.net>
 <connectionManagement>
  <add address="*" maxconnection="200"/>
 </connectionManagement>
</system.net>
```

the service code:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.PerCall,ConcurrencyMode =ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
  public class WithDrawService : IWithDrawService
  {

       int IWithDrawService.TestConcurrent()
       {
          return 1;
       }
  }
```

this service was deployed on the windows server 2008 r2 which has 2048MB memory

I found"set ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit" could solve my problem but i don't know where should i set it.   i tried to set it in my service class constructor and client but no effects.

Comment: Hi, not sure what you are trying to acheive.  You have your wcf service configured as a normal web service so it should handle multiple requests concurrently out of the box.  WHy do you think it isn't?

Comment: what is your exact problem ?

Comment: i made 10 call to 'TestConcurrent' method concurrently and hope all can return 1 but it didn't ,i don't kown where my code goes wrong or there's something missing